# Why I'm getting "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" error after redirecting URL?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-routing, redirect

[image]

This is my solution structure. 
When users hit in this **http://localhost/RouteUrl/** URL I want to redirect them to **http://localhost/RouteUrl/UI/MainForm.aspx**.

In web.config file within system.web section I've written:

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
  <add url="~/RouteUrl" mappedUrl="~/UI/MainForm.aspx" />
</urlMappings>
```

And when I browse *http://localhost/RouteUrl/*  it shows **HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory**
When I directly browse *http://localhost/RouteUrl/UI/MainForm.aspx* it simply shows the page, doesn't show any error.

I don't want to enable directory browsing. What I'm missing? How I should properly redirect  the URL?

Comment: Could it be possible .NET is not parsing your request and IIS is looking instead for a default document in the ~/RouteUrl directory?  Have you tried changing it to ~/RouteUrl.aspx (just to test the theory) and trying that way?

Comment: @Kyle B. I've add AnotherMain.aspx in UI folder. And changed the web.config to `<add url="~/RouteUrl/UI/AnotherMain.aspx" mappedUrl="~/RouteUrl/UI/MainForm.aspx" />` . Now when I browse http://localhost/RouteUrl/UI/AnotherMain.aspx it shows  HTTP 404 error.

Comment: Could you try adding <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> to the <system.webServer> element as well to ensure .NET is handling/intercepting the request?

Comment: Yes I've tried but still there is no hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find out the problem. The `~` itself points to the root directory and in `<add />` tag I've written `url="~/RouteUrl"`.

So the corrected `<add />` tag will be: 
    `<add url="~/" mappedUrl="~/UI/MainForm.aspx" />`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with the trailing /.  Your route is to ~/RouteUrl and you are entering ~/RouteUrl/, which would act as the root of a directory and with directory browsing is turned off, you receive a 403 error.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are trying to say. If you don't mind could you please re-write the `<add />` tag for me?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`
to the `<system.webServer>` section in the web.config works for me.